# How to see stored data in LiteDB-NoSQL

Tags: .net, litedb, nosql

I am learning LiteDB - NoSQL. I have go through the basic [example](http://www.litedb.org/). When I build it, it will generate Data Base File. Now, I just want to read this file to see the data I have stored. Is is possible to read it like we can see the data in MSSQL? How can I see the stored data?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

LiteDB comes with a shell console program. With this tool you can insert/update/delete or query any document in your data file. To download LiteDB Shell, go to http://github.com/mbdavid/LiteDB/releases

Some common commands:

- `open yourdatafile.db` - Open your datafile
- `db.your_collection_name.find` - List all documents inside your collection
- `db.your_collection_name.ensureIndex name` - Create an index in `name` document field
- `db.your_collection_name.find name = 'John'` - Search for documents with name = John
- `help full` - Show all commands in shell.

Comment: Hi Mauricio, Thanks for the wonderful LiteDB! Do you have any plan to port the shell console program to another platform such as Mac, using .NET Core maybe? ... I was looking for something like this for mac. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @IKnowNothingAtAll, thanks! Current shell versions supports are build only in full .net. But try compile shell app in .net core: all source are made using net standard.

Comment: Does this shell program still exist in v5? The documentation is only for v4 and I don't see it in releases.

Answer (score 8):

I have written fully fledged editor, which can be downloaded here https://github.com/JosefNemec/LiteDbExplorer

Comment: Thanks, it looks good from the first look! (but it does not remember the list of opened databases)

Answer (score 5):

You can find a bare bones viewer [here](https://github.com/falahati/LiteDBViewer/releases).

Answer (score 2):

You can use LiteDB.Studio which is developed by LiteDB original author.
As of today, it is in version 0.5.2 and works well for LiteDB v5.

https://github.com/mbdavid/LiteDB.Studio

Edit: it's Windows only.

Answer (score 0):

In PowerShell, for LiteDB databases you can use the module [Ldbc](https://github.com/nightroman/Ldbc).

It is the complete document store solution in PowerShell, batteries included.
But it may be used just for exploring data of existing databases.